# How to save any type of files in a specific folder using file upload in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a TextBox (txtDocUpload) and a Button. On the clicking of that button, an upload dialogue is opening and after uploading a file I have to save it in a particular folder.

For opening the upload dialogue

```
 private void txtBtnUpload_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        //openFileDialog.DefaultExt = ".txt";

        Nullable<bool> result = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
        if (result == true)
        {
            filename = openFileDialog.FileName;
            txtDocUpload.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filename);

        }
    }
```

Clicking save button I have to save, and the code ("File1"is the location where i want to save the file).

```
string urlpath = "WoDocs";
var path = @"~\" + urlpath + @"\" + WOMaintenance.GetAddressId.IDWorkOrderDetail;
if (!Directory.Exists(path))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

    var ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(txtDocUpload.Text);
    var pathURL=txtDocDescription.Text+ext;
    var file1 = System.IO.Path.Combine(path,txtDocDescription.Text + ext);
    //docFile1.SaveAs(file1);
```

Comment: It's not clear the question: what's your need? These methods does'nt fit for you? You need to do this on a MVVM pattern? Or what else?

Comment: Hello Stefano, my question is how do i save a file(any) to a specific folder using file upload dialogue. I am doing it in wpf. If you know any solution then please share the code and for upload i am using text box and a button.

Comment: @LagnajitPuhan: you can't save a file using any dialog. It isn't clear, what is "uploading" in your case, and why do you open `OpenFileDialog` and then `SaveFileDialog`. Better post the desired behavior, step by step.

Comment: Have you tried `File.Copy`?

Comment: @Lorek File copy is not working, throwing error "File not found".

Comment: Try it with fully qualified paths.

Comment: @Dennis : I am using OpenFileDialog to select  file for upload and i am checking with SaveFileDialog to save it in a folder. If you are getting confused with the code then ignore all the codes after creating directory and please write your code to save the file.

Comment: @Lorek What do you mean by fully qualified path? and "File1" is the path where i want to save.

Comment: I mean get rid of that ~ and use the actual drive name and all of the folders that make up the path to the file location.  Try starting simple and just copy to the same folder as the source file, but using a different file name. Create a simple example with as few lines as possible and show that so we can have a better idea of what is happening.

Comment: Thanks @Lorek i will try that and let you know what's happening.

Comment: Please don't give down vote, if question is confusing then i will explain it just don't give down votes a humble request.

Comment: I did not down vote your question, but I can understand why it was down voted. Basically, you should try to remove any code that is not directly related to your problem.  For instance, your Filter property is just noise. It would be nice for down voters to explain the down vote, though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a brief example:

```
    private void CopyAFile()
    {
        var source = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (source.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault())
        {
            var dest = new SaveFileDialog();
            if (dest.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault())
            {
                File.Copy(source.FileName, dest.FileName);
            }
        }
    }
```

This should demonstrate that File.Copy does work when you have access to the source and destination locations.

Comment: I have already tried this code, in this case if in my destination location there is no file then it is throwing an error and also if destination file is same as the source file name then it will not overwrite.